# Will installing Anaconda3 change Mac OS X default Python version to 3.4?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, anaconda

I'm planning to install Anaconda3 for Python 3.4. Since by default, Mac OS X uses Python2, will install Anaconda3 change the default Python version for the system? I don't want that to happen since Python3 can break backwards compatibility. If it does change the default Python version, how can I avoid that?

Comment: Have you considered installing the `python2` version of anaconda instead?

Comment: I've been using Python 3 and thought maybe I should install Anaconda3 instead. Or do you think it's safer/better to install the other version of Anaconda since I can create new environments any way?

Comment: I am not sure if it's better. I myself work almost exclusively with python3 at the moment and still have the python2.7 miniconda version installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple has a built-in system for managing multiple versions of software, and switching between them. But you don't even need to worry about that, because Anaconda installations are self-contained: Everything lives under the top Anaconda installation directory (probably `/Applications/anaconda`). The only effect outside this directory is that during installation, Anaconda will offer to modify the `PATH` variable in your `.bashrc`. If you agree, it will add **one** line at the end of your `.bashrc`, something like this:

```
PATH="/Applications/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
```

As you can see, Anaconda puts itself *first* in the system path. This means that typing `python` at the shell prompt will launch python 3, which may not be what you want. I run Anaconda 3.4 like this and have had absolutely no problems with my system, but I did need to modify my own executable python2 scripts that launched python like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

This is a nice way to find python wherever it is, but in this case it will find python 3-- oops! Changing the above to `#!/usr/bin/python` or to `#!/usr/bin/env python2` ensures that they continue to work correctly. In my experience this was not necessary with *any* of the system's own scripts; everything is already set up to find the right python.

**Alternative 1:** You could decline the PATH modification, and use Anaconda via the launcher. In that case there is **no** change to the rest of your execution environment. The launcher will start a special bash prompt with the anaconda environment activated, but execution in normal shells is completely unaffected. If you will continue to program a lot in python 2, this may be for you.

**Alternative 2:** A minimal-impact alternative is to put the anaconda directory *last* in your path:

```
PATH="$PATH:/Applications/anaconda/bin"
```

This ensures that non-anaconda binaries take precedence over anaconda, so `python` will start good old `/usr/bin/python` (that is, python 2). You can start anaconda's variant by typing `python3`, `idle3`, etc. I did not have IPython before I installed anaconda, so typing `ipython` finds the anaconda version.

Comment: Thanks for explaining! When I type `which python` at the command line after installing Anaconda, it returns `/Users/myusername/anaconda/bin/python`. How can I check which is the Python version the system is using?

Comment: Type `which -a python` and you'll see all executables named `python` on your path. Note that anything started from your bash will find the first python on the path. As I said this never caused me problems, but if you want `python` to continue to give you python 2, I can add how to my answer.

Comment: Thanks, it's fine if bash returns python3, as long as I haven't changed the system default to python3.

Comment: You can rest assured that you haven't. Since you installed anaconda in your home directory, you probably weren't even asked to authorize system changes by typing in your password, right?

Comment: No, I didn't have to type my password. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

No it won't, you can have multiple python installs, once you don't remove your system python or manually change the default you will be fine.